# Exception during dynamic array class pointer element creation

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I have a class

```
class Container
{

Container ()
{
...
}

...

};
```

And double pointer as a global variable

```
Container **models;
```

In `main` I do the next

```
models = new Container*[10000];
```

After that call

```
models[0] = new Container();
```

And get exception:

`access violation while trying to write address 0x00000000`

What’s wrong?

---

Wrong is that in the class

```
class Container
{
public:
int **ar;

Container()
{
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
ar[i]=0;
}

...

}
```

I forgot to initialize `**ar` array before initializing each `*ar` array. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: First of all please catch the crash in a debugger to see exactly where in your code it happens (and what the values of all involved variables are at that point). Secondly, if you want more help from us then please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and add a comment on the line where the crash happens (it might happen in the `Container` constructor or a function the constructor calls).

Comment: @Jarod42 I used to do it that way

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exception at `models[0]=new Container()` as I wrote that.

Comment: How do you *know* it happens on that line? Did you use a debugger? Debug "printing"? Some other method? And if you tried with `std::vector` and still had the same problem, it's very likely it isn't the `new` or object allocation itself, but a problem in the constructor. It's actually rather important that you show us a [mcve], because those few lines on their own can't lead to the problem you claim. Also please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude understood, and find my fault, thank You. I think I should delete or at least edit question